# Where can I enter my app specific password on appcenter.ms testflight integration?

Tags: testflight, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

With the new apple rule explained at https://developer.apple.com/support/account/authentication/:

> In an effort to keep your account more secure, two-factor authentication will be required for Account Holders of a developer program to sign in to their Apple Developer account and Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles starting February 27, 2019. This extra layer of security for your Apple ID helps ensure that you're the only person who can access your account.

I am getting the following error when trying to publish my iOS app on the store through the CI at https://appcenter.ms :

```js
{
  "mandatory_update": false,
  "release_notes": "feature/navigator profile (#467)",
  "destinations": [
    {
      "id": "678b39eb-7040-43ca-b903-REDACTED",
      "name": "App Store Connect Users",
      "message": "Failed to publish to store. Error: App specific password is mandatory for 2fa enabled account in service connection id: 5b1a378c-d7bc-4492-5ad6-REDACTED",
      "code": "app_specific_password_missing"
    }
  ],
  "code": "partially_succeeded",
  "message": "Failed to publish to store. Error: App specific password is mandatory for 2fa enabled account in service connection id: 5b1a378c-d7bc-4492-5ad6-REDACTED"
}
```

I have looked everywhere online and crawled around the different menus without finding anything of interest.

Do you know where I should enter my app-specific password?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can follow the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/stores/apple#adding-two-factor-authentication

Specifically:

**Adding Two-factor authentication**

If your Apple account has two-factor authentication enabled, App Store Connect requires an app-specific password as security. You can add an App-specific password to your account by navigating to Developer accounts in your [Account settings](https://appcenter.ms/settings/accounts).

- Hover over an item in the Accounts list.
- Click the three vertical dots on the right side of the list
- Select Update app-specific password.
- Generate an app-specific password using the Apple ID portal.

  - The name is for you to remember which service or app is using the app-specific password.
- Copy the generated app-specific password and paste it into the dialogue.
- Save by clicking Update.

Comment: I can confirm that while this is the method described on docs.microsoft, it does not work for me. I still receive the same error as OP after re-connecting to TestFlight from within App Center and generating/updating my app-specific password.

Comment: While this was working, as of today credentials for apple are failing and 2fa verification codes are always being rejected.

Comment: Amazing description, thank you for your input.

Comment: What if you don't have a list of accounts and are just getting setup for the first time? There's no 3 vertical dotes and no "Update app-specific password" option. If I try to enter the app-specific error while creating the account, it won't work. If I enter the actual Apple ID PW, my trusted device gets a 2FA verification code, but I have nowhere to enter the code.

Comment: This feature is now deprecated. It appears appcenter want you to use the Connect API method.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because of 2 factor authentication, you need to enter OTP for your apple app store ID.

Step 1: https://appcenter.ms/ open the app center click on distribute navigation link.
Step 2: Click on stores 
Step 3: you can see the error message to reenter your Apple connect credentials for the verification, it will ask for OTP. 
Now you can publish your app on app store.

Comment: After doing the above I can't type into the popup which says 'You don't have access to update this connection.'. Even though I have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by navigating to https://appcenter.ms/settings/accounts.